# IntelliJ does not show javac output

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

When running a build with and from the terminal, I get javac output properly formatted like so:

```
[javac] Compiling 99 source files to /Users/user/devdir
[javac] Note: Some java note
.
.
```

However, when I run the ant build script through IntelliJ, the only output I get is:

```
javac
```

I've tried using both the ant version packaged with intelliJ and the one used by the terminal (pointed it to the binary in my /usr dir) and I get the same result.  The project builds fine and everything else works as expected, I'm just not getting the debug information I want to see in the Messages pane.  Any ideas on why this would happen?

Comment: Does it help if you switch to the text output representation instead of the tree? It can be done using the corresponding button on the left of the tool window.

Comment: No, I actually prefer the text output representation so I've been using that.  I just checked the tree mode as well and it gives the same result.

Comment: @CrazyCoder This must certainly be a bug. I cannot see any of the `javac` output although the command line would show me very interresting things. I tried to change in every way I could think of. IntelliJ should not be that silent regarding `javac`.